# How to implement a withdraw function using call{value} and divide between accounts

Tags: erc-721, payments, reentrant-attacks

This [best practice](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/development-recommendations/general/external-calls/#dont-use-transfer-or-send) recommends using something like:

```
address private constant WALLET_A = 0xabcdabcdacbdbabskbkashda;

function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
    (bool success, ) = WALLET_A.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send to WALLET_A.");
}
```

rather than the `.send()` or `.transfer()` methods. What would be the best way to divide between multiple accounts?

```
address private constant WALLET_A = 0xabcdabcdacbdbabskbkashda;
address private constant WALLET_B = 0xbyzxyzyxzysxugauzgxuyzxz;
address private constant WALLET_C = 0xkwyeroiqgioqheqheqhweqhw;

function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
    uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
    (bool success, ) = WALLET_A.call{value: (balance / 100) * 17}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send to WALLET_A.");

    (bool success, ) = WALLET_B.call{value: (balance / 100) * 30}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send to WALLET_B.");

    (bool success, ) = WALLET_C.call{value: (balance / 100) * 53}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send to WALLET_C.");
}
```

Also, I've seen examples where the `payable` modifier is applied to the `withdraw` function as well as wrapping the address like `payable(WALLET_A).call`. Sometimes I've seen the `payable` only wrapping the address and not applied to the function. Other times neither like the example above. I want only the owner to be able to execute `withdraw`. If you leave the modifier off the function and wrap the payee address call, does that forward the gas to the payee? If you leave it off the payee and apply to the function, does that mean the owner who calls the function pays the gas?

The best practice mentions that `.call` does not mitigate reentrancy attacks, would it be enough to import the OpenZeppelin `ReentrancyGuard` contract and apply the `nonReentrant` modifier to the withdraw function?

Sidenote, solhint is giving me warnings about using low-level calls.

Comment: https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/re-entrancy/  I think this link might help you with the security question you have. And here is a good vide on the subject https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Mm3BCyHtDY&t=355s

Answer (score 0):

For best practice you can use payment splitter standard contract of open-zeppelin. For more information you can read the [open-zeppelin docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/payment) or you can you directly [payment splitter](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol) smart contract.

Comment: With PaymentSplitter, the accounts would pull from the contract whenever they want by calling the `release` function? For non-technical users, how would they do that? Does that mean the gas is payed by the puller? I'm wondering what the benefit is of PaymentSplitter vs a `withdraw` function that can only be run by the owner that pushes funds out.

Comment: The benefits of payment splitter you release payment account wise instead of all at once. Gas fee paid by account puller. In withdraw function gas fee paid by contract owner. Assume Wallet B wants to payment then owner must be call withdraw function and pay all gas fee but maybe Wallet A and C don't want to payment that but they can wait for more balance comes in smartcontract and after withdraw it. So that case your gas fee are saved and payment splitter contract admin doesn't care about when do call withdraw function that care of account share holders.